# Socket.io Not getting both Call back and data

Tags: socket.io

When using sockets I can do a call back from my client IF I specifiy just the callback. But if I add the data. The data will be present but my callback will be undefined!

What am I misunderstanding?

> ```
> class My Page extends React.Component {
>
>    doStuff(data)
>    {
>       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
>    }
>
>    componentDidMount()
>    {
>        socket.emit("path",this.doStuff)
>        socket.emit("path",this.doStuff, {"test":"yeah"})
>    }
> }
> ```

On the server side I have

```
 socket.on("path", function(callback,data)  
 {
     if(data && data.test)
     {
         callback(data.test)
     }
     else
     {
       callback("No Data");    
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the `emit` function in [Socket.IO's documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket-emit-eventname-args-ack) - its signature is as follows: `emit(eventName[, ...args][, ack])` meaning that it accepts an event name, arguments, and a function which will be called when the server answered the event.

What you need to do is the following:

**Server**: replace the order of your arguments in your `"path"` handler function, like this: `socket.on("path", function(data, callback) { ... })`.

**Client**: replace the order of your arguments when invoking the `emit` function, like this: `socket.emit("path", {"test":"yeah"}, doStuff)`.

That should work.

Comment: wow I feel dumb I thought I tried this but I think there was more in the way than I thought. I think I got a little lost in the docs! thanks